# Decide on baud rate for a project using Arduino Uno R3

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using an Arduino Uno R3 with the MPU 6050 to get motion data. Different example codes use different baud rates, without any proper explanation as to why.

So how do I know which baud rate is perfect for my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I most cases it doesn't matter!

In some cases the highest possible is preferred, as it prevents delays. That is when the buffer is full (when sending large amounts of data through the serial connection). As `Serial.write` will block until there is room in the buffer. In most cases this won't be an issue.

When running your arduino at slower speeds, you have to select a lower baudrate, or the micro-controller can't keep up.

When connection to other devices (e.g. GSM shield) using serial, that device may require a specific baudrate.